# How do I view contract balance in Ganache?

Tags: erc-721, ganache

When testing locally with Ganache, how can I view the balance of ETH sent to my ERC721 contract as part of payable functions(minting)?

I have simple mint functin

```
    function userMint(uint256 numberOfTokens) public payable{
    require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_MINTS_PER_TXN, "Exceeded max tokens in a txn");
    require(msg.value == (numberOfTokens * mintPrice), "Incorrect amount of ETH sent");
    //TODO validate tokens are still available (havent sold them all)
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= numberOfTokens; i++) {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        //EMIT EVENTS
    }
}
```

WHen I call it via truffle console I can see that the eth is paid but I don't see it "received" in the contract anywhere in ganache.

Comment: What's the code your working with?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the mint function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example;

Note that ETH is not a contract so there is no balanceOf() method to be called.

This is how it's done.

```
uint balance = address(this).balance;
```

`address(this)` is your contract address.

This is done inside you contract with solidity so the balance will be available inside your contract.

You can also get it from the cli

Check out these methods.

https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/ethereum-and-clients/test-rpc/#implemented-methods

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this

uint256 balance = address(this).balance;

return balance;

Comment: Yes this works.  I'm just curious if I was doing something wrong that ganache wasn't showing it.